# VBA that will count number of rows until it hits a dark blue cell? (RGB = 93, 123, 157)

Tags: excel, vba

Starting in cell B8, I want to count the number of rows down until we hit a cell that is filled with the RGB 93, 123, 157.

I tried using the autofill formula feature while recording, but the cell references stayed absolute: `Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A182")`

This will only work if the report has 182 rows, which they won't all have.

I was also given this to try:

```
Sub Test()

Dim i As Long, bluerow As Long

For i = 1 To 10000
    If Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(93, 123, 157) Then
        bluerow = i
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

Range("B6").AutoFill Destination:=Range("B6:B" & bluerow), Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub
```

But it doesn't put any numbers in column B.

Comment: by using dwirony's suggestion, whatever B6 contains should be applied to the autofill range. If B6 has no value the rest won't either. Would be easier to help if you provided a screenshot, my guess is that you don't really need to locate the blue row..

Comment: Works for me. You forgot to declare `Workbook` and `Worksheet` in your code. Instead of using `Range("B6")....` use `YourWorkbook.YourWorksheet.Range("B6")....` the same goes for the `Cells(i, 2)` statement. Or you can put `With YourWorkbook.YourWorksheet` <place all code here>`End With`

Comment: Thought I'd hinted you towards using SearchFormat. Have you tried anything like that yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could work by itself.

```
Sub NumRws()
    '"Cells(5, 2)" is a reference to B5(for some reason, shouldn't it be B8? in that case it should say "Cells(8, 2)")
    '"Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)" refers to the last used cell(a cell with any value) in column A
    '".Offset(-1, 1)" offsets the second reference to column B and now also one row up("-1,")
    '..and "Range(...)" combines the two
    '".FormulaR1C1 = "=ROW()-4"" applies the formula which results in row number minus 4(if you change to B8 it should be -7)
    Range(Cells(5, 2), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1)).FormulaR1C1 = "=ROW()-4"

    '..Also if you just want the result of the formula do the following instead
    With Range(Cells(5, 2), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 1))
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=ROW()-4"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This actually works pretty well, however the blue cell is being counted.  Any idea how to make it stop at the row right above the blue cell?  Otherwise this works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Nevermind I got it.  I'm surprised it was this simple of a code; thank you AsUsual!  It seems to be working fine.  I'll try it on different reports to see if it stays uniform.

Comment: @Helpplease sorry for late response, if it's still an issue see edited code with explanations

Answer (score 0):

The code below uses `Find` to get the first cell in column B that matches the color criteria, and then subtracts 7 from the row number.

```
Sub FindtheFirstColoredCellCountRowsfromRow8()
'Find the first cell in Column(2) with specific interior color and count number of rows
    Dim fndCel As Range, cnt As Long
        ActiveCell.Interior.Color = RGB(93, 123, 157) 'colors any cell to use in "Find"

        Application.FindFormat.Interior.Color = ActiveCell.Interior.Color 'store cell color in find

        'set the find range variable to find the first cell that matches the color in Column B
        Set fndCel = ActiveSheet.Columns(2).Find("", , , , , xlNext, , , True)

        cnt = fndCel.Row - 7 'set the count variable by subtracting 7 from the fndCell row

        MsgBox cnt

        Application.FindFormat.Clear 'reset FindFormat

            ActiveCell.Interior.Color = xlNone 'clear the cell you used to set the color to find
End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't use `Application.FindFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(93, 123, 157)` instead of referring and painting an activecell?

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak good point, easier, just trying to show that there are multiple ways to accomplish instead of looping and counting each cell.

Answer (score -1):

Not exactly sure what you're asking for? You want the row number to appear on every cell from B8 till the row where it appears? in that case use:

```
range("B8:B" & bluerow) = bluerow
```

This will type the row number where the RGB value is found, starting from B8, down to where the RGB was found. If this is not what you need please explain your problem further.

EDIT: Oh, my bad. Then use this:

```
For i = 1 To 10000
    If Cells(7 + i, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(93, 123, 157) Then
        Exit For
    Else
        Cells(7 + i, 2) = i
    End If
Next i
```

I would suggest finding the last row, though, instead of using "to 10000", you can use:

```
LastRow = cells(rows.count,2).end(xlup).row
```

Comment: Not the row number, but a count with 1 starting in B8.  Then I want it to count the rows all the way down, until we hit that blue cell.  I don't want the row with the blue cells to be counted though, I want it to stop right above that.

Comment: Edited my answer, that does the trick. Edit: Just saw you already got an answer, great!